# Link my Logo to homepage html

Tags: html, css

I want to make my Logo in my header clickable and link to the homepage but i don't know exactly how to do this right.

My code:

Navigation menu:

HTML

```
<div id="myMenu">
            <div class="myWrapper">
                <nav>
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#myMenu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 999; 
    background-color: #252e30;

}
.myWrapper
{
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 156px;
    height: 30px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-size: auto 43px;
    background-image: url(../images/mylogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I want my logo make clickable and link to the page: Homepage.cshtml

Comment: Just enclose it in an anchor tag `<a><img src="logo.png" /></a>`.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using CSS to set your logo as a background image, what would be wrong with using the `img` tag, surrounding by a link? Like so:

```
<div id="myMenu">
  <div class="myWrapper">
    <nav>
    <a href="/"><img src="../images/mylogo.png" height="30" width="156" /></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

This has the added benefit of being more accessible (especially if you use an `alt` attribute on your logo), which makes search engine bots happier. Image content that conveys meaning to the user should never bet set using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You better use an image wrapped in an anchor-tag.

But else this should work:

```
<div class="logo" onclick="window.location.href='homepage.html'"></div>
```

Comment: This is bad practice as it will break in browsers without JavaScript (or with it disabled).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a background image a link. Move the image into the HTML code, and then make that a link.

Comment: This is misleading. An element can have a background image and be linked, visually making the background image the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myMenu">
         <div class="myWrapper">
             <nav>
                 <a href="Homepage.cshtml"><div class="logo"></div></a>
             </nav>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh ok it works that's fine, no nonsense here.. as you've just stated..it works.

Comment: @JackAllen just because it works, doesn't mean it's correct and will validate. But in this case, you *are* right, as long as the document in HTML5.

Comment: @soyuka [some reading on wrapping block elements with a](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links).

Comment: Thanks MikeSmithDev I really thought that this was not valid.

Comment: Its suggesting that everything within the `<a>` tag is a link to the href so there is nothing wrong with using this, its the same as an `<a>` around anything else surely

Comment: @JackAllen if it is HTML 4.01, **[its wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/1810243)**.

Answer (score 0):

also it can be like following example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #000000;">     
      <div class="logo" >
            <a href="{% url 'major' %}">
                <img src="{% static 'images/logo.gif' %}" style="width:80px;height:80px;"/>
            </a>
      </div>
      .....
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an `<a>` instead of the `<div>` for the logo..